# Postgres: Why do I get an input syntax error when modifying a char column into a timestamp?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I copied data from a csv to my table. However, the timestamp data was copied with the column on the table as char(40). Now I want to modify the table to have it as a timestamp but keep getting an error specifying input syntax error.

The data is formatted in ISO8601 I believe

e.g. 2016-06-03T08:00:00.020584124-04:00

I've tried both of these SQL statements with the same result

```
ALTER TABLE public.data
    ALTER COLUMN timestamp TYPE TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE USING timestamp::TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE;

ALTER TABLE public.data
   ALTER COLUMN timestamp TYPE TIMESTAMPTZ USING timestamp::TIMESTAMPTZ;
```

UPDATE: Turns out when I used psycopg2's copy_from, it read the header values. That explains why I had problems trying to change any of the values that were char(). Once I used copy_expert and specified that the csv contained headers, I was able to use the TIMESTAMPTZ data type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ALTER` statements are both ok. You believe the values are in ISO8601, but there are some that are not. You can try to find them using regexp, e.g.:

```
select *
from public.data
where regexp_replace (timestamp, '\d{4}-\d\d-\d\dT\d\d:\d\d:\d\d\.\d{9}-\d\d:\d\d', '') <> ''
```

Btw, it is a bad idea to have `timestamp` as a column name.

Comment: You were right. Turns out when I used psycopg2's copy_from, it read the header values. That explains why I had problems trying to change any of the values that were char(). Once I used copy_expert and specified that the csv contained headers, I was able to use the TIMESTAMPTZ data type.

Answer (score 0):

You either need parenthesis to support the colons (`::`) syntax) or you should convert it slightly different:

```
ALTER TABLE public.data
    ALTER COLUMN "timestamp" TYPE TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE
    USING TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE "timestamp";
```

Since `timestamp` is a reserved word I would recommend naming your field differently.

Answer (score 0):

I would first write a select statement that converts the data correctly to timestamp. 
    Select x,y,z, to_timestamp(timestamp,'Format') from data

Where format is defined https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html

Then just add a
    Create table data_new as 
In front of your select query

Lastly drop table data and rename the new table

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's a very bad idea to name a column "timestamp" since it's a reserved name for a type.

In the `USING` clause you can provide an expression used to compute the new column value from the old. You just do simple assignment cast `timestamp::TIMESTAMPTZ` which is default.

It should be something like that:

```
ALTER TABLE public.data
    ALTER COLUMN "timestamp" TYPE TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE
    USING to_timestamp("timestamp", 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS');
```

The problem is that you have nanoseconds that can not be parsed. You can parse it as microsecond (add US: `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS US`) but it will give you bad result. Here is the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-formatting.html) on Data Type Formatting Functions.

If you can omit microsecond that would be OK. But if not, you should write your own parsing function and use it in the `USING` clause.